# Can I retrieve user followers order by the most one who retweet the user tweets

Tags: twitter

Can I retrieve user followers order by the most one who retweet the user tweets

for example:

user screen_name = aaa

followers:

bbbb  retweet 30 times

cccc  retweet 70 times

dddd  retweet 50 times

gggg  retweet 20 times

ffff    retweet 90 times

how can I retrieve the followers order like this:

ffff
cccc
dddd
bbbb
gggg